# Gesture Detector or Inkwell onTap property not executing for a Specific Area [IOS]

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

Gesture Detector or Inkwell not working for the area just below appbar when I give a padding of 5 ,It is working fine .
The issue is just for IOS ,as on Android it works fine.

```
              GestureDetector(
            // splashColor: Colors.transparent,
            // highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(
                context,
                Routes.clubsList,
                arguments: {
                  "clubs": clubs,
                  "isMyProfile": true,
                },
              );
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: Spacing.space8, top: Spacing.space8),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    S.of(context).profile_more,
                    style: theme.textTheme.body2Regular
                        .copyWith(color: theme.colorScheme.textSecNeon),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  Semantics(
                    label: 'my_guilds_more_icon',
                    child: BaseImage(
                      height: 12,
                      width: 6,
                      asset: LocalAsset(
                          url: 'assets/images/ic_arrow_right_blue.png'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```